# c++ way to enlarge size of array by two?

Tags: c++

This is my current code. Is there a nicer way to do the same in c++?

```
{
            // create more room in array
            Point *temp = new Point[pointList.getSize()*ENLARGE_TIMES];

            memcpy(temp,pointList._pointList,sizeof(Point)*pointList.getSize());
            pointList.~PointList();
            pointList._pointList = temp;
            pointList.setSize(pointList.getSize()*ENLARGE_TIMES);
            pointList._pointList[iterator] = point;
            iterator++;
            pointsCounter++;

            continue;
}
```

**EDIT: can't use a vector**

Comment: you can't make an array large without allocating new memory. I suppose a more graceful way to do that is using linked lists

Comment: `pointList.~PointList();` Are you manually calling a destructor?

Comment: Why yes, there is. It's called a standard container, such as `std::vector`.

Comment: @Jason, I believe he's doing that to replace the old array

Comment: The best way to do it is using [`std::vector::resize`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/) :):):)

Comment: as others have pointed out, you can use that library. Otherwise, the best way to implement allocating a larger amount of memory is using linked lists

Comment: std::vectorize your code

Comment: As others have said, some STL container is a better solution, but no one has mentioned the "old school" `realloc()` functions - not ideal for C++, but what you are doing is largely the reason they existed in C.

Comment: Doing a dynamic array well is somewhat non-trivial. http://coderscentral.blogspot.com/2012/08/c-dynamic-arrays.html

Comment: STL will help you in many ways. Once you get used to it, you'll love it because you'll see that you'll be doing things pretty fast and efficiently. So, don't hesitate to learn it, learn it well.

Comment: We cannot possibly answer your question in any sane way without knowing what that destructor does but chances are that the code is a disaster; manual invocations of a destructor is almost always a sure of that. Following that with further manipulation of the object? *shudder*

Comment: @Tom why can't you use a `std::vector`? Under what circumstance would that not be a possibility for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to avoid using an external library, you may implement a linked list for your code. Although you may have to rewrite other parts of your program, it is an efficient way to handle dynamically growing memory in C++. I believe that std library provides [templates](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/) for creating these structures. If you would otherwise like to implement them yourself, here's some snippets to get your started:

The structure:

```
struct PointNode {
    int point;
    PointNode * next;
};
```

Adding data:

```
void addPoint( PointNode ** head, int point ){

     PointNode * temp = new PointNode;

     temp->point = point;

     temp->next = * head;

     * head = temp;
}
```

Freeing memory:

```
void freeNodes( PointNode * head ){
    PointNode * temp;

    while( head ){
        temp = head->next;
        delete head;
        head = temp;
    } 

}
```

When you need to use the data as an array:

```
int getPoints( PointNode * head, int ** points ){

    PointNode * temp = head;
    int i = 0;

    for( ; temp; temp = temp->next, i++ );

    ( * points ) = new int[ i ];

    for( i = 0, temp = head; temp; temp= temp->next, i++ ){
        ( * points )[ i ] = temp->point;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Example:

```
int main( ){

    PointNode * head = 0; // make sure the head is always initialized to zero

    addPoint( &head,  4 );
    addPoint( &head,  5 );
    addPoint( &head, -4 );

    int * points;

    int len = getPoints( head, &points );

    for( int i = 0; i < len; i++ ) cout << points[ i ] << endl;

    delete points;

    freeNodes( head );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Depends what you're doing. A vector is most efficient in most general cases. The OP seems to be pushing onto the end anyway, and vectors are good at that.

Comment: I don't disagree with you, but Tom has brought up that he cannot use that library

Comment: Well, I meant the data structure itself. I'm assuming `std::list` can't be used either. Neither of them is overly bad to implement unless you're going for the gold while you do.

Comment: @chris I would like to know, though, how anything can be more efficient than a linked list ( in terms of dynamic arrays )

Comment: For starters, having contiguous memory can be a big advantage. It's honestly not usually that bad at managing new allocations, either. Allocations don't happen that often, and you're left with a nice block of contiguous memory.

Answer (score 1):

As Chris points out, you really want to use std::vector, along with methods reserve() and push_back(), like so:

```
vector<Point> pointList; // could be a member variable
pointList.reserve(INITIAL_CAPACITY); // up to you
pointList.push_back(point); // adding new elem
pointList.end();  // replaces your iterator

// Some idiomatic iteration code to go with it:
for( auto iter = begin(pointList); iter != end(pointList); ++iter )
{
  Point p = *iter; // deref iterator and use result
}
```

Comment: Student exercise?  In that case, I'd use realloc().